# merge or join pandas dataframe with sqlite table?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a large sqlite table that should not be loaded all at once in memory with columns `['a','b','c',...]`. It has a composite index for the columns `a` and `b`.

```
a    b     c   ....
1    34    45656 .....
54   175   34323 ....
102  12121  3029 ....
```

Now I want to extract rows that have particular values of `a` and `b`, so I'm thinking of making a query like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE a IN <insert tuple of a vals> AND b IN <insert tuple of b vals>`

However, there are *thousands* of such combinations of `a` and `b` that I want to check. I can create a pandas database that contains these combinations:

```
>>> df
    a    b
    102  12121
    234  879789
    ...  ...
```

and it might be simpler to just join or merge the two tables.

However, I don't want to add another table to the `sqlite.db` file because I can make different `df`s, and I don't want to keep inflating my sqlite database file size. Is there a way to create a temporary table in the sqlite db for merging? Or is there a way to do this via pandas?

Comment: Please show how you can create the combination in pandas as there might be a way to do it in SQL. You do not describe what particular values need to be extracted from `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Parfait the values that need to be extracted are given in `df` which has thousands of rows. If the sqlite database were to be read into pandas like `sql_df = pd.read_sql(table, engine)`, then what I would need is `sql_df.merge(df, on=['a','b'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the index on `a` and `b`, querying for each combination of `a` and `b` should be more efficient than creating new data structures in either Pandas or SQLite AND performing a join.

You could loop over each combination of `a` and `b` and query, or you could do it in one query, but you're limited by `SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH`:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a = <a1> AND b = <b1>) OR (a = "a2" AND b = <b2>) ...`

Comment: Hi @Ken, there are thousands of such combinations of `a` and `b` though. That would be one long query, or I would have to process the data files in smaller chunks. Is there any faster alternative?